# Angular login after token expiration

Tags: angular, authentication, openid-connect, okta

My Angular app needs to check for token expiration before making service calls. Before it gets to this App, a NodeJS/Express+Middleware routing app manages authentication to the OIDC service. Please note, this is for rather large company which already has an OIDC token issuing server (sorry not sure what this is called).

If the token expired, it needs to re-route the whole app over to a login page. I asked earlier and learned I need to add an AuthGuard to my Angular app to facilitate this. I think I have a good example and could do that, except for the part of detecting an expired token. Somehow, I need to check whether the session is authenticated.

I'd like a package that can check these 3 states for me:

- Token isn't there, user needs to log in. This part should most likely be handled by the middleware authentication server mentioned above. Nonetheless, if somehow a user got to the app, the AuthGuard routing will be notified and the app will redirect the user to the login page.
- Token is there, but expired. If this is the case, the AuthGuard routing will be notified and the app will redirect the user to the login page.
- Token is there, is valid. If this is the case the AuthGuard lets the user do what they intended.

In the middleware package I used Passport. For Angular, I didn't want to figure out what header or cookie I need to check, figure out how to parse the value, check an expiration or otherwise. I'd look into okta, but I wasn't sure if they wanted you to use their authentication server. I wish to have the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider the case where you have the login component under one module, and the rest of your routes under another module, this will be called the ExampleModule.

You can pass a guard to the Example modules like so:

```js
export const layoutRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'examplePage',
    loadChildren: () => import('./example/example.module').then(m => m.ExampleModule),
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  }
]
```

In the AuthenticationGuard you can call a service that will clarify if your use can move forward or not:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private _auth: AuthenticationService, private _router: Router) { }

  /**
   * Implementation of the CanActivate interface that evaluates whether the
   * user is allowed to access the given route.
   * @param route ActivatedRouteSnapshot
   * @param state RouterStateSnapshot
   * @returns a boolean that the router uses to allow/refuse navigation
   */
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    const isAuthenticated = this._auth.canNavigate();
    if (!isAuthenticated) this._router.navigate(['/login']);

    return isAuthenticated;
  }
```

Some points:

- The AuthenticationService is the one with the code that dictates if a user is authenticated or not, this code is not spread accross the application.
- The guard only navigates to the route if the result is true, otherwise, it navigates to the login page again.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was trying to get a suggested package for OIDC based authentication that would provide the implementation for the above isAuthenticated. I was considering okta but wasn't sure if that was specific to some server they implemented.

Comment: If thats the case, I believe you should a separate question for it, specifically asking about the openind-connect/okta and only mentioning that you are using angular. As you presented the question its not clear what you are asking, hence my answer not being very usefull and generic.